# Using an AppSetting to set inline ConnectionString name

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

Trying to do something like

```
<%$ ConnectionStrings: AppSettings:ENVIRONMENT %>
```

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to try:

```
<%$ ConnectionStrings: System.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ENVIRONMENT") %>
```

Otherwise, if using .NET 4.0, consider using the XML configuration file transforms: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx

Brian

Answer (score 0):

The ConnectionStrings syntax is just an [ExpressionBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.expressionbuilder.aspx) - there's nothing specific about the property it sets that requires it to come from the [ConnectionStringExpressionBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.connectionstringsexpressionbuilder.aspx).

There's already an [AppSettingsExpressionBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.appsettingsexpressionbuilder.aspx), so you *may* be able to chain them - something like

`<%$ ConnectionStrings:AppSettings:ENVIRONMENT %>

I'm not too confident of that approach working, though. So, you'd probably be best off [writing a custom ExpressionBuilder](http://aspalliance.com/1113_Creating_a_Custom_ExpressionBuilder_in_ASPNET_20.1) - they're pretty painless and can be mighty handy.